# Play Framework Encrypting Passwords in application.conf

Tags: playframework-2.1, password-encryption

I'm using Play 2.1.x and I'm wondering if there is a way to encrypt passwords that might be needed for database access? I have a configuration entry that stores the database server url, user credentials for accessing the database and I do not want to leave my password as plain text. How can I have my user credentials encrypted? I want to later un-encrypt when I use them within the context of my Play server. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is where would you store the decryption key.  If you store it in the same (or similar) configuration file, the entire exercise is moot.

I am guessing that you do not want to put the plain text password in application.conf to avoid having it show up in version control system.  One way of mitigating that kind of leak is to have a different store for sensitive configuration files for production systems (a different repository that has fewer accessors works nicely).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you meant by "different store for sensitive configuration files for production systems"?